# Git lfs (missing) object, on push, even if it shouldn't be

Tags: git, git-lfs

I try to push to a new remote repository via git lfs, but error occurred.

```
(missing) PathToFile (SHA256)
```

Files are not in the folder, and shouldn't be there, but lfs is trying to find them and give a missing error. I don't have access to some old lfs files so I tried to fix this with

1. `git  fetch --prune`
2. `git push --prune git@example.com:/new-location.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`
3. `git lfs push origin --all`
4. `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`
   `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`
5. `git rm -r --cached .`

Question- How can I delete from lfs cache (I guess) or how in general I can escape from this missing object?

Comment: *Git* knows nothing of these files. The way Git-LFS works is that the LFS wrappers hide the *real* files *from* Git, and have Git commit "pointer files" instead of the real files. Git only knows about the pointer files. The LFS wrappers do all the real work here, and any messages you get are from Git-LFS. (This isn't useful in terms of fixing the problem, but is useful in terms of eliminating Git from the search space: Git has nothing to do with the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone find this related, this is how I fixed

1. `java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files PathToFile`
2. `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`
3. `git lfs push origin develop` to check and push

For more information: [bfg repo](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)